# How to create multiple payment options

Tags: html, paypal, payment

I am looking to implement a donations form on a political party website, but rather than using the default single "Donation" button I would like to have a menu with multiple payment options, much like the form found here: https://www.oaklandgop.net/donate.

I can't seem to find this option on the PayPal's basic button creator, so I'm assuming this must be done with custom HTML? Sorry if this question has already been asked; I wasn't able to find any relevant answers on the forum.

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 1):

You wont find an option like this for the basic button creator.  If you are wanting to accept the credit card information on your site, you would have to use Pro.  There wouldn't be a problem with collecting any of the other information as the form would be on your site so you could ask for what every infomration you want.

If you use standard, you can collect the information on your site and pass it over to PayPal during the payment flow.  However if you are using standard, you would also need to redirect the buyer over to PayPal to enter in their credit card informatioin and make the payment.

You do have a few other options as well.  For example you could use Express Checkout.  With Express Checkout the buyer would have to enter in the credit card information on PayPal's page or log into their PayPal account to make a payment.  However, you could set up the flow in the following way.  The buyer selects the amount that they wish to make a payment for.  You make the SetExpressCheckout API call and get your token back.  You redirect the buyer over to PayPal where they enter in their credit card information or sign into their PayPal account and agree to the payment.  They are then redirected back to your site, where they fill in the rest of the information, and then you execute the DoExpressCheckout API call to complete the payment.  You could also collect the information up front as well.

There are also hosted pages you could use as well to do something similar to this as well, but if you are wanting the buyer to enter in the credit card information on your site and keep this all in one form, your best option would be to use pro.